# Seemingly good account unable to login

Tags: centos

Noob here.  I have a few bare metal CentOS 7 minimal OS installs.  They each have local accounts for Docker mostly.  I have 3 boxes where the account seems fine (ie. not locked, reset the password) however I am unable to login. Simply says "Access denied" whether I put the correct to bogus password in.  If someone can please tell me where to look.  Thank you.

Comment: First place to look would be `/var/log/secure`

Comment: Thank you mehlj - it's saying failed password but I know i'm using the correct password: Oct 15 11:00:24 B.... sshd[1064]: Failed password for gl...sm.. from 192.168...... port 59023 ssh2
Oct 15 11:00:33 B... sshd[1064]: Connection closed by 192.168..... port 59023 [preauth]

Comment: So this is over `ssh`? `/var/log/messages` may have more info from `sshd` about the failures. Also, check in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure you have the line `PasswordAuthentication yes`. Might be worth checking if you can `su` as one user to another on the machine to rule out an account issue. If you can, then the problem is likely with `ssh`.

Comment: check your /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Sounds like you have the `PasswordAuthentication` option set to `no`.

Comment: Thank you.  Here are the findings.  PasswordAuthentication was equal to Yes.  I don't see any discernible information in the /var/log/messages but I aslo don't know what to look for.  I can su - username over to the problem account if i'm root (it does not ask for password).  When I attempt this from non-root, it asks for a password, then I get the following "su: Authentication failure"